# Quarkus custom parameter injection for handling complex objects

Tags: java, spring, quarkus

I hope to find help here because I'm struggling for quite a long time to find an elegant way to custom parameter injection using quarkus (maybe with help of one of the many handy extensions). What I was thinking was something like spring's HandlerMethodArgumentResolver in this link: [text](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-creating-a-custom-handlermethodargumentresolver/)

Thus far I haven't found a decent way to handle this (pun intended)
Thanks in advance!

searching for alternative implementations but ended up not being satisfied. Maybe got I got drifted away and lack the experience of being successful to find anything of value.

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#parameter-mapping

Comment: We'll need more information about what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: I don't have a specific case or goal. Colleagues and I were just wondering if there was something similar to spring the HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. The link to resteasy seems to reflect at least a similar approach, so thank you very much